# Loud banging noise after car put in for service - what did they do?

Tags: brake-calipers

I would really like some advice. My car went in for MOT and the handbrake needed fixing as it was insufficient in the rear offside. They changed the pads, disc and eventually caliper. After picking the car up I noticed a really awful banging sound, like a helicopter propeller. I took it back to the garage this morning and barely made the drive there as the sound got louder and eventually there was some very loud bangs just as I arrived. I left my car with them and they have repaired it (for free) but they have been very coy with revealing what the actual issue was. I would like to add that this is after consistently rude and poor service from them throughout. I am just curious if anyone can shed any light on what the issue might have been.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It would be very hard for any of us to make a judgement as to what was going on. Suffice it to say, it sounds like THEY messed something up. The good part of it all was they were willing to fix whatever wasn't right without charging you extra. As a complete guess, I'm thinking they didn't reattach a caliper like they were supposed to, which ended up dragging and causing the noises.

Comment: Possibly loose wheel nuts.

Comment: Was it just a noise, or were there vibrations that went along with it? Did you notice a difference in how it drove?

Comment: It didn't feel all that different when driven but to be honest i was so alarmed by the noise I might not have noticed. When I asked what the issue was they eventually said it was the calliper on the other side (not the side they fixed) and given how much they charged me for the one they did fix i find it hard to believe they would have sorted the other one for free unless they were somehow at fault. My young children were in the car. They were just so rude everytime I asked a question.

Answer (score 5):

It's quite possible that after they put your wheels back on the car, they forgot to properly torque the wheel nuts (aka lug nuts) as @HandyHowie said in a comment. If this is so and you continued driving a bit longer than you did, it's quite likely that one of your wheels could have come off while the car was in motion, with potentially disastrous results.

The reason for their coyness is either embarrassment for their amateurish,  unprofessional and potentially fatal mistake, or because their error actually caused damage to your vehicle and they hope you don't notice.

I recommend that you have your wheels, wheel nuts and studs checked immediately by another garage or by someone with hands-on auto mechanical experience.

You are looking for damage that would look like this on your wheels and studs:

[image: e]

It's possible that only one wheel has this damage. You probably won't be able to see the damage without removing the wheel nuts. They can be removed and replaced one at a time without jacking up the car, and naturally the nuts must be properly torqued upon being reinstalled.

If you see damage like this, the wheel with damage and the damaged studs must be replaced because they are unsafe. Don't delay both for your own safety and to reduce the chance that the "coy" mechanic could claim that there was no such damage when your car left the shop. If you have this damage, they owe you one or more new (or good condition used) wheels, including mounting and balancing of your tires, plus new studs and/or nuts if damaged. Possibly a wheel hub too if the studs have loosened.

Photo credit: meaforensic.com

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely have this checked.